# LinkedIn OAuth Request with no Verifier

Tags: api, oauth, linkedin-api

**Introduction:**

Hi everyone, i am currently writting a lib to make generic OAuth Requests in C#.

The first part, of getting a Token and a Token secret is working for Twitter and Linkedin already ( RequestTokens ), but as soon as i jump to the Authorization part it does not work for Linkedin,but it does for twitter.

**Useful Informations**

I am currently using a method to generate `AUTHORIZATION_URL` for the Request. For Example :

```
https://api.linkedin.com/uas/oauth/authorize?MyToken
```

Same for Twitter,using its own url. Both services are getting a correctly generated URL, and the window that pops up when i copy it in the browser is correcly.

After the user hits the button, different things happens depending on the service.

1 - Twitter : The browser redirects me to the Callback Page, and on the url there is a Verifier that i am currently parsing and storing it. Perfect.

2 - LinkedIn : In the sample i have,everything works just as twitter does, but when i use my own lib, there is no redirect for the callback url,instead, i am getting redirected to a url with a `oob?` tag, and a verifier number is shown in the screen, instead of appearing in the querystring.

**Doubt:**

What should i do to make sure that the OAuth method i will be using is the Normal one,instead of the `Out Of Band` method. I am making sure that the `CALLBACK URL` that i set in the lib, is being used for the Signature on the First Request (REQUEST_TOKEN STEP). Also, twitter works when i do this.

Any idea of whats happening ? Let me know if there is any useful information i can add to make sure that my question will be as complete as possible.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

I solved it.
I forgot to add the Callback parameter to the Signature in the BaseGenerator,instead, it was commented.

Thanks anyways for everyone